# How can I bring keyboard to edit a field when a UIViewController is shown?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, on-screen-keyboard

I want to show the keyboard just after a view controller is being pushed to start editing a specific UITextField.

I believe that I should manually fire the event on the ViewDidAppear.

Which is the proper way of doing such tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you need `IBOutlet UITextFiled *yourTextField;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated or viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call [super viewWillAppear/didAppear:animated] - just in case

Answer (score 3):

To make keyboard appear you need to manually set your text field as a first responder:

[textField becomeFirstResponder];

It can be called either in `viewWillAppear:` or in `viewDidAppear:` method - whichever provides best behaviour for you.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` if you want to start editing just after the views got displayed.